# Quantstrat error in instrument class constructor

Tags: r, stock, quantstrat

HI i am tryning to copy the code from Ilya Kipnis's "Nuts and Bolts of quantstrat I".  i loaded the following code:

```
 require(quantstrat)
 require(PerformanceAnalytics)
 initDate="1990-01-01"
 from="2003-01-01"
 to="2012-12-31"
 options(width=70)

 options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
 currency=('USD')
 Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

 symbols<- c("XLB","XLE","XLF","XLP".....
  if(!"XLB" %in% ls()) { 
  suppressMessages(getSymbols(symbols, from=from, to=to, src="yahoo",    adjust=TRUE))  
  }

 stock(symbols, currency="USD", multiplier=1)
```

but get the following error?

```
  Error in instrument(primary_id = primary_id, currency = currency,   multiplier = multiplier,  : 
  currency USD must be defined first
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

to define a currency

`currency(‘USD’)` should be used and not

`currency=(‘USD’)` as in your code above